# How to scale SVG element to fit parent element using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

Simple code below:

I am trying to copy a svg element in the document and append it to another element.

But I need to **resize the svg to fit the new element** only using JS.

```
const $SVG = $('svg').clone();

//Resize SVG

$('li').append($SVG);
```

Comment: Does `li` have defined dimensions (height and width) ?

Comment: ya I can access it with `$('li').css('width')` if thats what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using CSS:

```
li{
  width: [some dimension in px];
  height: [some dimension in px];
}
li svg{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about jQuery but you could take a look at a script i wrote that helps scale a svg path with it's parent element by adding a simple attribute, `data-rel-d`.
Check it out here: 
https://github.com/mrdivinemaniac/RelativePath.js